# Unable to capture the closest span element on mouse click

Tags: javascript, dom, mouseevent

The [MDN specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) of the `closest` method reads that the method traverses the DOM upwards, in the direction to the document root. But what method does one need to use in my case instead of `closest` then?

In my HTML page I have the following code:

```
<div class="slider__steps">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span class="slider__step-active"></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

In my JS file I want to capture the closest `span` element to a mouse click and change its CSS class. I try to do this as follows:

```
moveSlider(elem) {
    let sliderSteps = elem.querySelector('.slider__steps');
    let spans = sliderSteps.querySelectorAll('span');
    elem.addEventListener('click', moveThumb);
    function moveThumb(event) {
      for (let span of spans) {
        span.classList.remove('slider__step-active');
      }
      event.target.closest('span').classList.add('slider__step-active');
    }
  }
```

But the error I get is

> Uncaught TypeError: event.target.closest(...) is null

How does one actually catch these spans on mouse clicks?

Comment: DOM elements with zero pixels size can't be clicked

Comment: @MisterJojo This seems quite surprising. How is it possible to toggle these span elements' classes then?

Comment: Please [edit] with a [mcve]. With CSS etc.

Comment: how can you imagine to click on something with no size ?

Comment: I see, I need to handle this in a different way. Thanks for pointing this out.